# Current Thread Method java

Tags: java, multithreading

So I am trying to work with threads for a game I am making. I am **very** new to the subject so I may not understand correctly. My question is how does the currentThread() method work in the Thread class of the java API. The API says "Returns a reference to the currently executing thread object.", but as far as I understand multiple threads run at the same time. How is it possible to return only one executing thread?

Comment: you should read some tutorial about threading.

Comment: I think they should have named it getSelfThread() or something like that, because there can be more than one currently executing thread with multicore cpus.

Answer (score 7):

The code that calls `currentThread` will be executing in one of the threads, not in all of them, so it can get that thread specifically.

Answer (score 5):

When an instruction in your code is executed, it is executed within a specific thread. This is the thread returned by that method.

Obviously, if a specific method is executed by multiple threads, each execution might return a different value for `Thread.currentThread()`.

You could try this short example to get a better idea of what is going on and in particular the fact that the 2 threads execute in parallel. You should see that t1 will run a few loop then t2 will do the same and back to t1 etc (you might need to increase the number of loops from 5 to a higher number depending on your machine):

```
public class TestThread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
                }
            }
        };

        Thread t1 = new Thread(r, "t1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r, "t2");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you need to print out the current thread in a loop? Once should suffice, I would think.

Comment: I like your first 2 sentences...but the rest of the post, especially the code, seems vague enough to be misleading.

Comment: @Jeffrey the idea was to show some interleaving where one thread might run the loop twice then the other one goes active etc.

Comment: @chris Same comment. I should probably have been more explicit about it.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you have list of instructions printed on a piece of paper. A person reads the instructions and performs them. The instructions are a program. The person is a thread. You could make many copies of the paper and pass them out to many people. If the instructions say something like, "slap yourself," *yourself* refers to whomever is reading that instruction from that paper. Likewise, `Thread.currentThread()` refers to the thread that is executing that call to `currentThread()`.

Answer (score 0):

"The currently executing thread" means that the system scheduler gave some time to this thread to execute its code.

Answer (score 0):

When writing a single threaded application, you can reason on your program like a series of instruction, each executed after the previous one is finished (this is a rough approximation, but conceptually compilator and processor try to simulate that and work as if this was really what was happening).

When you use multiple thread, each thread has its own series of instruction. A new thread when created is passed a entry point (a method), and will continue executing from them. Each thread is independent from the other thread in their execution (it will simply execute one instruction after the other), though they share memory and thus side-effect from one thread can affect another.

So for some code to be executed, it must be done in the context of one thread (there is one created by the operating system when your application start, that start its execution at the `Main` method). When the function `currentThread` is called, it is in one of those context.

The java runtime when creating a thread will store a reference to that `Thread` object in the thread context, and the `currentThread` will just lookup there and return the current thread.

Answer (score 0):

At any given point in time, only one thread will be executing(live), so `Thread.currentThread()` returns the details of the currently executing Thread. e.g., Thread_name, priority, method_name.

Answer (score -1):

Multiple threads are not running at the same time and there is thread switching between multiple threads. Processor can execute one task at a time so one thread at a a time executed. So we get the reference of currently running thread.

Comment: Multicore machines really do run multiple threads at one time.  I got a massively-multithreaded program (with highly interactive threads) working on a single core machine, then moved it to a machine with 4 cores.  That was a real education.

Comment: "Multiple threads are not _neccessarily_ running at the same time..."